# submit without page redirect

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, xmlhttprequest

I want without page redirect when user click submit button.
Here I was posting only `userid`. I want to post `password` too.

This is my HTML text area and button:

```
<input type="text"  name="user" id="user" value="" placeholder="Mail-Id"><br>
<input type="text"  name="userp" id="userp" value="" placeholder="Password"><br>
<input type="button" name="checkuser"   id="checkuser" value="Validated" onclick="test();">

<script>
function test()
{  
    var username = document.getElementById('user').value;
    var url = "login.php?user="+username;

   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
var result = xmlhttp.responseText;
            if(xmlhttp.responseText!='')

            {
                document.getElementById('use`enter code here`r_status').innerHTML =result ;
            }
        }
     xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);

    xmlhttp.send();

}
</script>
```

```php
<?php
include_once('B810.php');
$Email = $_REQUEST['user'];
//$password = $_REQUEST['userp'];
$Q810_1 = "SELECT SIGNUP.EMAIL,SIGNUP.PWD FROM SIGNUP WHERE SIGNUP.EMAIL='".$Email."'";
// AND SIGNUP.PWD='".$password."' ";
$R810_1 = mysql_query($Q810_1);
$O810 = mysql_fetch_assoc($R810_1);
if (($O810)) {
    echo 'success';
    // header("Attendance.html");
    // exit();
} else 
    echo 'failure';
}
//mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Where's the `php` codes?

Comment: Add it in your question for better format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this code

```
var username = document.getElementById('user').value;
var url = "login.php?user="+username;
```

To

```
var username = document.getElementById('user').value;
var password = document.getElementById('userp').value;
var url = "login.php?user="+username+'&password='+password;
```

Comment: why show the password in the url?And OP said POST, not GET